# How to set timeout for web service call

Tags: apex, webservices, httprequest, timeout, httpresponse

I want to call out my web service after the insert process of a custom object with a delay of 2 minutes. But i am getting that exception `FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: Read timed out` How can i fix that problem ? Here is my implementation.

Callout class:

```
public class HttpCallout{
    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void getContent(String url){
        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(2000);

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        String response = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(res.getBody(),'UTF-8');
        System.debug('***response****'+response);
    }

    public void serviceCaller(){
        getContent(url);
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger AfterInsertOrUpdate on Sales_Order__c (after insert) {
    System.debug('Making future call to update account');
    HttpCallout httpCallout = new HttpCallout();
    httpCallout.serviceCaller();
    System.debug('After Insert');
}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 5):

The argument to [HttpRequest.setTimout](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setTimeout) is a millisecond value so for 2 minutes:

```
req.setTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);
```

**PS** With the clarification that the desire is to make the web service call after a 2 minute delay I suggest you experiment with this [Need System.schedule cron string for run once](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37310/need-system-schedule-cron-string-for-run-once) approach. In your case you would build the cron string to be 2 minutes from the current date/time.

Comment: I tried that but the web service has been called out just after the insert process.

Comment: @user3864408 Perhaps a better title for your question would be "How to schedule a web service call for 2 minutes in the future".

Comment: Yes it is then how can i make it ?

Comment: @user3864408 See link in PS.

Comment: i didnt understand anything from the link i think this is not what i am looking for

Comment: What i want to do is calling this web service 2 minutes after the insert of custom object.

Comment: @user3864408 Right so call System.schedule using a pattern that is 2 minutes in the future - see the link in the answer.